# BTCJam API 500 errors

Tags: client

I am currently trying to set up an application using the BTCJam api. I think the api could be very useful, but I have been unable to get it to work fully, and since support isn't responding, I thought I would post here. I am using https basic authentication (not oauth).

First off, while I am able to make the request for current open listings (the "listings" method), none of the other requests work. When I try to get data on my own profile (the "me" method) or on my open listings (the "my_open_listings" method), I get an internal server error (500). Is anyone else having this problem? Are those methods simply not available right now, or is there a difference in how I should be making the "listings" call, which is working for me, vs. the other GET requests listen on the api FAQ page? From the documentation, it seems that all GET requests are authenticated the same way, with all settings and parameters (none) the same, but just a different method. So why is one of the methods working while the other 4 throw 500 errors?

And second, though there is plenty of information about the user behind any given listing, there is one giant absence: the user id/alias. Am I missing something? Is there some other way to find out the alias behind a given listing? Or did they intentionally leave that information out?

Any help on either of these matters would be greatly appreciated. If support gets back to me, I will post their answers here.

Thanks,
Paul

Comment: no response from support in a couple of months, and no help from bitcointalk either. I need you now more than ever bse!

Comment: I've bumped this to a [FB community](https://www.facebook.com/groups/btcinvestors/) where the CEO of BJ is occasionally responsive. There are also a few users in there who have had some successes with the API...

Comment: @lalalalalalalambda, thank you for putting me in touch with the facebook community. Hopefully I will find some answers soon.

Comment: I'm voting to close this four-years old unanswered question as off-topic because BTCJam closed in May 2017 so issues with their API are probably no longer of any interest to anyone.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because BTCJam closed in May 2017 so issues with their API are probably no longer of any interest to anyone.

Comment: Just flaged the question as a "in need of moderator intervention" case, announcing them of BTCJam mission complete!